# I want to be able to switch windows in gnome overview with the same key i used to open overview like in macOS

Tags: linux, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, manjaro, dconf

I recently switched from macOS and I need to be able to switch overview windows from the same keybinding like in macOS mission control how can I do this?

I have looked for shell extensions, and for settings in dconf, and normal settings, I found nothing pls help.

On Manjaro, gnome 40.

Comment: What was the key binding used in OS X?

Comment: I would press the function row button, and use the same to choose a window.